# Preparing custom / arbitrary sequence counter

Tags: counter, sequential-logic

I know following types of counters:

**Asynchronous counter**

> Clock input of each flip flop is output of earlier flip flop.[[ref]](https://www.allaboutcircuits.com/textbook/digital/chpt-11/asynchronous-counters/) 
>   [image]

**Synchronous counter variant 1: with ANDing for flip flop inputs**

> Note that in this variant of synchronous counter, we have ANDed outputs of earlier flip flops to form input of next flip flop. [[ref]](https://www.allaboutcircuits.com/textbook/digital/chpt-11/synchronous-counters/)
>   [image]

**Synchronous counter variant 2: with ANDing for flip flop clocks**

> Note that in this variant of synchronous counter, we have ANDed outputs of earlier flip flops to form clock of next flip flop. [[ref]](https://www.amazon.in/Digital-Principles-Applications-SIE-Leach/dp/9339203402/)
>   [image]

I know how we can prepare custom / arbitrary sequence counter with synchronous counter variant 1. These two pages give examples: [1](http://barrywatson.se/dd/dd_counter.html), [2](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/design-counter-given-sequence/)

Consider the diagram from second page:

[image]

So it seems that to obtain arbitrary sequence, we need to form inputs of flip flop by some combinations of outputs. Does that mean, we cant construct arbitrary sequence counter following other two approaches, asynchronous counter and synchronous counter variant 2, as in both of them inputs of all flip flops are tied to HIGH logic?

Comment: Your "synchronous counter variant 2" is really an asynchronous counter. Synchronous means that ALL FFs get the exact same clock.

Comment: I believe synchronous mean flip flops change their output states together. It might be achieved by different implementations and not necessarily with the same clock applied to all flip flops. I may be wrong as I am not electrical / electronics major. But I referred to the mentioned reference book. I dont know if its wrong in the book itself. Also I know that most sources / books dont really discuss this approach. But I feel variant 2 circuit output too behaves like synchronous counter. Nevertheless, I believe, the question stays valid.

Comment: As noted by Dave Tweed, synchronous counters get *exactly* the same  clock; aribitrary sequences are usually done (for JK types) by changing the J and K inputs prior to the next clock.

Comment: Please note that, in variant 2, all flip flops still gets same input clock, just that it is ANDed with outputs of earlier gates. So I guess it should still behave like sync counter. Also from the timing diagram it looks like sync counter. I can confirm that the book does indeed specify it under synchronous counter section. The book pdf is available online, but I dont know if it is rightful to link it here. You can find relevant page [here](https://i.postimg.cc/VL3mKY4M/malvino-leach.png).

Comment: (continued from earlier comment) @PeterSmith by "aribitrary sequences are usually done (for JK types) by changing the J and K inputs prior to the next clock", do you mean arbitrary sequence counter cannot be prepared by two methods: async and sync variant 2 (regardless of whether it is really sync or async)?

Comment: @anir Arbitrary sequences can be done for both synchronous and asynchronous counters; note that gating the clock introduces a delay and therefore the clock for flip flops 2 and 3 in variant two do *not* get the clock at the same time as each other or the first flip flop and it is therefore not synchronous.

Comment: These are -ve edge triggered flip flops. So they toggle when clock pulse transition from HIGH to LOW. In async counter, this happens when earlier FF output change from HIGH to LOW. In sync variant 2 counter, we are ANDing clock and FF outputs. In sync variant 2 diagram, Y = A AND B AND clock. Say A = B = logic 1, but when clock change from HIGH to LOW, Y also changes HIGH to LOW and toggles final FF. A and B will also start changing, but due to ANDing with clock, rightmost flip flop dont need to wait for either A or B to go LOW. So cumulative delay does not occur.

Comment: (continued from last comment) Also, can you give link to async arbitrary sequence counter example?